# How Do You Add Multiple Frameworks & Extensions to a JSFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

Have not used JSFiddle in a while and can find no info on the UI updates...since when I can't recall. Anyway under the JavaScript gear setting is a list of common frameworks. It does not allow for multi selection....how can I add more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only choose one framework using javascript setting selection. But you can always add a link to CDN for other resources that you need using the external resources link on the left.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why can we only add one on the right side? I don't remember having to track down CDN's when I used to use JSFiddle.

Comment: @Mikee Don't know the reason behind it. But ever since they changed the ui, its working this way. Ideally you should be able to pick the ones you want with checkboxes :)

Comment: Thanks, I can't even get a 'hello world' jQuery to run in JSFiddle now that they have changed it all up....no docs, no FAQs, no nothin now....I guess it's time to find another JS playground.